# my android phone keeps asking sign in to wifi network.

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

My android phone keeps asking "sign in to wifi network" I'm wondering because I have a signal but I can't access. Please help to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

This usually means that you've accessed the WiFi network, but you need to log in to some database for it to grant you internet access. Some form like this should appear once you click on the notification.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot of a *[captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)* (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Okay. Thank you for that term. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be connected to that network, open your web browser and it redirect you to the sign in page where you have to agree to the terms and agreements of the network. Then, it should allow you access to the Internet.